# What's the best way to make the driver wait until a condition is true and continue if it's false?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

The workflow I'm automating is for generating a report. The report takes an X amount of time with each time it's generated (ie. it could take 10-50 seconds). I can't think of a good way to make the driver wait until the report generates AND continue if the ExpectedCondition doesn't occur. Currently, I can intentionally fail the test by asking the driver to look for an expected condition "Your Report is complete**s**" but the problem is that it won't continue to the try catch from here. That is the last line it will run.

**Workflow:**
Main page where I start report -> Report generator popup window (wait up to 50 seconds) -> TWO POSSIBLE SCENARIOS: 1. "Another report is running, try again later."  2. "Your Report is complete"

**My selenium code:**

```
//explicit wait
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + "Your Report is complete" + "')]")));



try{

    Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Your Report is complete."));
    log.info("Your report was generated."); 
}

catch(AssertionError ex){
    log.error("Your report was not generated.");
    throw ex;

}
finally {
    driver.close();
    // change focus back to old tab
    driver.switchTo().window(oldTab);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

**Page source code when the page is successfully generating the report:**

```
<html>
    <HEAD>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <TITLE>Generating report</TITLE>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            @import url("public/css/main-new.css");
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/Modal/prototype.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/Modal/scriptaculous.js?load=builder,effects" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/Modal/modalbox.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/tooltip.js" ></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/modalbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/tooltip.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="JSUtility.js"></script>

    </HEAD>
    <body style="margin: 25px;">
        <form method="post" action="LaunchReport.asp" id=form1 name=form1>
            <input type="hidden" name="REPORT" value="3diFevJrtGSy9AhdaEtY8Lh5N.xls">
            <input type="hidden" name="REPORTFINAL" value="3diFevJrtGSy9AhdaEtY8Lh5N.xls">
            <input type="hidden" name="PPVS" value="CELL5572">
            <input type="hidden" name="TYPE" value="AUDIT">
            <input type="hidden" name="CLASS" value="DEFINED">
            <input type="hidden" name="T" value="3">
            <input type="hidden" name="MT" value="540">

        </form>

            <p><b><font class="mdtext">Your Report is complete.</b></font></p>
            <p><font class="mdtext">Preparing to download....<br></font></p>
            <SCRIPT>
document.form1.submit();</SCRIPT>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);

try {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + "Your Report is complete" + "')]")));
    // If you get here, the condition did not timeout and so the
    // report was generated.
    log.info("Your report was generated.");
}
catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    // Timed out, the report was not generated.
    log.error("Your report was not generated.");
    throw ex;
}
finally {
    driver.close();
    // change focus back to old tab
    driver.switchTo().window(oldTab);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

If you must generate an `AssertionError` you could always do this in the catch clause:

```
catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    // Timed out, the report was not generated.
    log.error("Your report was not generated.");
    Assert.assertTrue(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Louis!  I was really trying to come up with this solution since I already had a try catch in place but didn't know you could catch a timeout exception.  Sure enough, I tried out your solution and it worked like a charm!  Thank you!